How to fill a gap between baseboard heater and wall safety?
What is safe and effective for filling gaps around a heater? I asked my landlord about it and he kind of shrugged it off as not being a problem but bugs come in since this started happening. When I first moved in in September 2020 there was barely a gap there. But it’s become progressively worse. He feels the previous owners must have caulked it and it is no longer effective. I’d like for this gap to be taken care of. I know they don’t care if I do minor repairs myself. Is there anything safe I can do to fix this and still be able to use the heater? I’ve noticed the room doesn’t get as warm when heat is on in winter as well since this got worse.





I see a small gap where the trim looks like it is separating in the picture to the right. I also se a large space that may have something to to with the heater, I guess. The picture is a bit blurry, an a bit too close to see the context of you question with it. There are areas on heaters where the air needs to circulate, and I can't see where these gaps pertain to that possibility.

Sorry about that I’ve just taken three more and added them to the post.

I see there is separation of the heat unit to the wall. It can be drawn back in place by lifting either "door" on either end of the cover. Using a stud finder or other means to locate the framing in the wall, you can add more screws to draw the cover back to the wall.
The door I refer to, may be painted in place and will take some effort to open up without bending it in a way that will keep it from closing again.
The screws or nails that original held it in place are usually in the top edge, you may need to lay on the floor to look up to see where the screws will go. Many times there are predrilled hole to use. They may be close enough, or should be close enough to find a stud at one or more of them.
There is a chance you will see the original fastener that has released it's hold that allowed the gap to occur. If so use a screw there to draw it back in.
